# Login & Authentication in Chrome Extension Practice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and trying to implement an authentication method (firebase). I'm confused by what has to go where, since the popup.html doesn't allow inline script, it makes it a bit more difficult.
As far as I see this there are 2 options:

1. Call external page (hosted by me) from the extension, open in new tab, handle login there. But in this case, how does the extension communicate with the login page? Cookies? I need the confirmation inside my popup.js
2. Try to handle Email/Password login in Chrome extension popup, which seems more complicated. I always violate the Content Security Policy, bit annoying. I tried this already, problem is once you close the popup, it looses the login state.

I researched already a lot, but there is no real good example so far, and other questions are barely answered. Thanks!

Comment: What about using [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) in the background script sending [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from the popup?

Comment: This might work for OAuth applications such as Facebook right? I'm trying to implement the native Firebase login.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to have the login/password input boxes in the popup but run the actual login code in the background page. You can do that sending a message from the popup to the background page or directly from the popup using something like:

popup.html:

```
<input type="text" id="email">
<input type="password" id="password">
```

popup.js:

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage){
    bgPage.performFirebaseLoginWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
});
```

Since the background page is always on, the login state should be preserved when the popup is closed.

Comment: So yes, I think this works, eventhough it leads to another error, but this doesn't seem to be related to this, but rather seems like a security issue, I opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764706/

Comment: @iván-nokonoko I have created a chrome extension to use as a convenient way to access an internal collaboration tool used within our team. In that extension I have a login form inside a popup and the login works fine. But if I close popup and leave it closed for some time, it appears to loose the session. When I open the popup after that I have to login again. Any idea what this happens? Is it because I don't have a background page? I have all login code inside popup itself.