# Firebase results in “Auth/network-request-failed” on device only

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have a Cordova/ionic/angular app that uses Firebase auth and works perfectly in a browser and in an emulator. On a real device, however, calls to firebase.auth() return error-code "auth/network-request-failed", indicating that a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. This occurs when I run device-debug from, in my case, Visual Studio but also when I install the app on a device (Android phone) and simply run it.

The firebase code is:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

I have already replaced the `<form>` stuff with simple `<div>`s in the template because I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860900/firebase-project-results-in-auth-network-request-failed-error-on-login) that it could cause a re-submit which triggers the network error. I have tried the button both with a `<button>` directive and with the `<a>` directive. No difference. Unless angular or ionic do some magic that messes up the directives, this ought to be clean but you never know.

The following security meta-tag is also included as it was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764706/chrome-extension-auth-network-request-failed-when-communicating-with-firebase) as a possible solution to the problem:

```
<meta "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com https://www.googleapis.com https://securetoken.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'" , "permissions": [ "https://*/*", "activeTab" ] >
```

The js code shouldn't be the issue as the app is working fine in a browser but I am including it anyway:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then(() => { ... }
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
   });
```

Lastly, I have an `onAuthStateChanged` observer attached. The observer does get initialized on the device but it never fires - of course - because the `auth()` call returns an error.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: To be any help troubleshooting, we'd need a working repro to verify and tinker. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For your own efforts, I'd start by [turning on debug logging](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/ed3236d26e60ab3b4b855f89f20df517), which may shed some light in where the failure occurs.

Comment: I found a workaround rather than a solution: created a brand new cordova project and copied the www path from the malfunctioning project. Firebase works like a charm after that, even when debugging a device.